# How to export dataframe to CSV in Tkinter python2.7?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I am trying to let the user add three entries and the code will use them to get data from an API and then export the data to CSV. I am trying to do it like this but I am not sure what is the issue and I am still new on Tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
import csv
from urllib import urlopen
import json
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
start2 = StringVar()
end2 = StringVar()
root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
root.title("Data")
startd = "2017-13-03"
endd = "2017-13-03"
power1 =""
ID = "1232.4343.323"
class data1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        #frame.pack()
        Tops = Frame(root, width=1600, height=1000, bg="powder blue")
        Tops.pack(side=TOP)
        self.output()

        thelabel = Label(Tops, text="Data",font =('arial',30))
        thelabel.pack(side=TOP)

    def output(self):
        Label(text='Start Date:',font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack(side=LEFT,padx=12,pady=12)
        self.startd = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.startd.pack(side=LEFT,padx=2,pady=16)
        Label(text='End Date:',font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack(side=LEFT,padx=12,pady=12)
        self.endd = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.endd.pack(side=LEFT,padx=2,pady=16)
        Label(text='Device ID:',font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack(side=LEFT,padx=12,pady=12)
        self.ID = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.ID.pack(side=LEFT,padx=2,pady=16)

        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.getjsondata)
        self.b.pack(side=LEFT,padx=20,pady=5)

    def getjsondata(self):
        global power1
        url1 = "https://api.data.com/mongo/measures/"+ID+"/"+startd+"/"+endd+"/?format=json"
        power1 = urlopen(url1).read()
        power1 = json.loads(power1)
        power11 = pd.DataFrame(power1)
        power11.csv(power11, file="MyData.csv")



b = data1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The data comes in a json format and this is how the data comes:

> [{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:47:00Z","value":"423"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:47:30Z","value":"419"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:48:00Z","value":"431"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:48:30Z","value":"429"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:49:00Z","value":"422"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:49:30Z","value":"427"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:50:00Z","value":"426"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:50:30Z","value":"427"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:51:00Z","value":"428"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:51:30Z","value":"426"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:52:00Z","value":"424"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:52:30Z","value":"423"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:53:00Z","value":"453"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:53:30Z","value":"433"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:54:00Z","value":"445"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:54:30Z","value":"438"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:55:00Z","value":"430"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:55:30Z","value":"437"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:56:00Z","value":"425"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:56:30Z","value":"420"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:57:00Z","value":"431"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:57:30Z","value":"435"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:58:00Z","value":"443"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:58:30Z","value":"430"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:59:00Z","value":"425"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T19:59:30Z","value":"406"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:00:00Z","value":"412"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:00:30Z","value":"417"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:01:00Z","value":"422"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:01:30Z","value":"422"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:02:00Z","value":"418"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:02:30Z","value":"415"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:03:00Z","value":"423"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:03:30Z","value":"411"},{"timestamp":"2017-01-14T20:04:00Z","value":"413"}]

I have filtered the data using panadas, my main issue is how to link an entry to a variable that I could use in my code. The entries are: 
ID: 
Starting date:
Ending date:

Please let me know what is the issue in my code.On the other hand I am planing to give the user the open in where to save the csv file on his computer if that is possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If problem is on `pandas` side:

It seems you need [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) and then if need select data by `timestamps` use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.read_json(url1).set_index('timestamp')
print (df)
                     value
timestamp                 
2017-01-14 19:47:00    423
2017-01-14 19:47:30    419
2017-01-14 19:48:00    431
2017-01-14 19:48:30    429
...
...

date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-14 19:47:00')
var = df.loc[date, 'value']
print (var)
423
```

Comment: This answered the issue of the csv but I it keeps giving me an empty csv because I think it is not taking the inputs as variables. If I change url1 to a correct url (without linking itto the inputs) then it gives me data in the csv. So how to delcare the inputs as variables?

Comment: And your solution works `power1 = urlopen(url1).read()
        power1 = json.loads(power1)
        power11 = pd.DataFrame(power1)` ?

Comment: Also I seem your `url1` is created from 3 variables. If check `print (url1)` it return right url?

Comment: it prints the url1 yes but it takes the first inputs, it doesn't take the entries and fill them in url1. So I guess my issue is in declaring the entries as variables that I could use in url1.

Comment: Hmmm, so it is tkinter side and unfortunately I cannot help you, because no idea how it works.